# How to convert camrec to mp4 using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, avi

I raise such problem but in the same post I raise the solution.

The first thing to know is that the .camrec format (from Camtasia) is a compressed file, so we must first decompress these files before converting them to .mp4.

Using 7z it is possible to decompress a .camrec file, and generate a .avi:

```
7z e "*file.camrec" "file.avi"
```

The second thing, is to convert this .avi file to .mp4 with ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i "file.avi" "file.mp4"
```

If someone has a better solution I invite you to post it here.

Answer (score 0):

Camtasia file format is a **colsed** and composed file with multiple assets and instructions called MS-CFB. The binary header does not correspond to 7zip, rar, zip or gzip. You can not conver `.camrec` from `ffmpeg` or `unzip`.

In Microsoft website says: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-cfb/68530324-9d3d-4441-9ea9-66a2c8f79567

> [MS-CFB]: Compound File Binary File Format

```
000000: D0CF 11E0 A1B1 1AE1 0000 0000 0000 0000 ................
```

And i have a `.camrec` file for the example:

```
whk@machine:~/Vídeos$ file fest.camrec;
fest.camrec: Composite Document File V2 Document, Cannot read section info
whk@machine:~/Vídeos$ head -n 16 fest.camrec | xxd;
00000000: d0cf 11e0 a1b1 1ae1 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

The best option is download Camtasia Studio and install it on a Windows machine and export the project as video file format.